# Unit Test Service method Consuming Soap Service

Tags: junit, mockito

In my spring based rest services I have a service method that returns a token, the method actaully consumes a Soap Service, I am not able to decide how to write a unit test for that. The method signature is below

```
    public String methodName(){
    String token="";
    try {

    token =  util.getSoapService();

    }catch(Exception e){
   }
return token;
}
```

Can I use Junit and Mockito to test this code

Comment: I did something Like this
Util mockUtil = Mockito.mock(util.class);

Mockito.when(mockUtil.getSoapService).thenReturn("some string");

String token = mockUtil.getSoapService();
get a null pointer Exception on the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a mock implementation of service, assign it to `util` variable and implement expected behaviour. After it check trat token value is correct.

Comment: I did something Like this
Util mockUtil = Mockito.mock(util.class);

Mockito.when(mockUtil.getSoapService).thenReturn("some string");

String token = mockUtil.getSoapService();
Got a null pointer Exception on last line

Comment: @avenirit12 And do you have any issues with this test?